# Execute a join query in Talend Open Studio for data integration

Tags: mysql, join, sql-update, talend, data-integration

I am new to Talend open studio, I need to execute a MySql update query in a job. So I tried using `tMysqlrow` component and specified the query in Query field. When I run the job it shows "Lock wait timeout exceeded; try restarting transaction" error.

Here is my SQL query:

```
UPDATE library_export AS updater INNER JOIN 
(SELECT id,(max_sequence_3 - coreTable.Level_3_sequence)+1 AS reverse_sequence_3,
(max_sequence_2 - coreTable.Level_2_sequence)+1 AS reverse_sequence_2,
(max_sequence_1 - coreTable.Level_1_sequence)+1 AS reverse_sequence_1 
FROM library_export AS coreTable 
LEFT JOIN 
(SELECT MAX(Level_3_sequence) AS max_sequence_3,Level_2_id 
FROM library_export 
GROUP BY Level_2_id) AS level3 ON (coreTable.Level_2_id = level3.Level_2_id)
LEFT JOIN 
(SELECT MAX(Level_2_sequence) AS max_sequence_2,Level_1_id 
FROM library_export GROUP BY Level_1_id) AS level2 ON (coreTable.Level_1_id = level2.Level_1_id),
(SELECT MAX(Level_1_sequence) AS max_sequence_1 
FROM library_export) AS level1) AS updataBy ON (updater.id = updataBy.id) 
SET updater.Level_1_new_sequence = updataBy.reverse_sequence_1,
updater.Level_2_new_sequence = updataBy.reverse_sequence_2,
updater.Level_3_new_sequence = updataBy.reverse_sequence_3
```

Can anybody help me to execute the update query?

Comment: @davejal last three lines of the code.

Comment: if you run this query directly at mysql commandline/database does it work fine?

Comment: @garpitmzn yes, if I run this query in command line it works fine, I can able to update the required fields.

Comment: "Lock wait timeout exceeded" - does it show immediately or it take a while? Are you sure nothing locks this table?

Comment: @xto when I run this query its shows immediately nothing locks, but it shows "Lock wait timeout exceeded" only when I try to execute this in Job.